# page_style not being applied when using Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using Paypal's Adaptive Payments (Preapproval API) for one of my projects.

Everything is working fine, the payments are processed exactly as I want. My only problem is that I can't use the `page_style` variable as i could with a classic PayPal refirection solution.

When I obtain the pay key for PayPal, I prepare a form like this:

```
<form method="post" id="gateway_form" name="gateway_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&amp;preapprovalkey=PA-XXXXXXXXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="mystyle">
    <button type="button" class="continue-with-payment" onclick="checkDonateForm(327, 'gateway_form');">
    <span>Proceed to Payment</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Where `mystyle` is a custom page I have created on my Paypal account which is the application owner.

I have also tried to send page_style as a GET variable e.g. `https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&amp;preapprovalkey=PA-XXXXXXXXX&page_style=mystyle` but nothing happened.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page_style` variable is for Payments Standard transactions - not Adaptive Payments. I checked to see if there was an equivalent for Adaptive Payments but there doesn't seem to be.

I'll submit a Feature Request asking to include one but I cannot guarantee that it will be implemented - sorry.

Comment: Thank you. I supposed that `page_style` variable is not supported on Adaptive payments but its better to read that from an official source :)

Comment: Just found this while fighting the same battle. I tried both adding `page_style` to the URL and `pagestyle` to the NVP data. Setting the custom page style to be `Primary` for the account has no effect, and the default page style cannot be modified. Sigh. One more vote for the Feature Request.